# How do I avoid format errors using matplotlib in Google Colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

[Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjLcA.png)
I am trying to plot time series data from a csv in google Colab and am getting the following error:

ValueError: Unrecognized character a in format string

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/hospital project/fastpass stuff.csv")

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df_all_units = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='30min')]).size().reset_index(name='number of events')

df_all_units.to_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/hospital project/all_units.csv")

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot('number of events', 'date')
plt.title('Visitors Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Number of Visitors')
#plt.show()
```

Comment: What line does it fail on? Please give a full error message/traceback.

Comment: I have found the error is on plt.plot('number of events', 'date') line and the exact results of this program have been added to the question in an image